# Applying SBAS corrections properly

Tags: gps

The SBAS standard, RTCA-MOPS, contains lots of unclear information. I am trying to implement SBAS corrections by the help of EGNOS SDK which is an open source software by ESA.

When I apply long corrections, results get worse. Fast and ionospheric corrections make it better or worse.

Can you suggest any more detailed documents and source code?

Comment: I thought these corrections were used in real time to improve gnss position accuracy, you are trying to do it in postprocessing right?

Comment: No, I am working on a real time GPS receiver of which I have the source code. GPS accuracy is good, but SBAS corrections, especially long corrections, ruin it.

Comment: Did you do any advancement? Seems the SDK is no longer supported.

Comment: @jinawee Unfortunately no. I haven't been working on that topic for 6 years or so. And it seemed like a dead-end. We did code reviews with other colleagues as well, but we couldn't find the problem.